# JsonIgnore only when sending GET request

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a .net Web API and having trouble. I have a /Users endpoint that supports CRUD operations. I don't want the password field to show up in the response for obvious reasons, but I do want to be able to POST to /Users and send the password field (when creating a new user).

Currently I'm using [JsonIgnore] which does what I want in the case of GET /Users, but I get this error:

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details
```

when I try and POST a user. This is because the password field is not being sent due to the [JsonIgnore] tag. How can I fix this?

Here's my model:

[image: User Model]

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple ways to do it, but the cleanest way is to actually create two classes that are trimmed for its usage or make the property virtual and have the deriving class override the password property and add the attribute.

```
class Base
{
    public virtual string password {get;set;}
}

class Derived : Base
{
    [JsIgnore]
    public override string password {get;set;}
}
```